# How should I translate "If I have some" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, words

Hello I'm learning Japanese since the beginning of the school-year and for my homework I have to describe what I do in general everyday.

I'd like to translate:

> Then I do my homework if I have some.

I have the beginning:

> それから しゅくたい を します "if I have some".

I only know the hiragana and katakana, I'm not supposed to use Kanji, can you help me please?

Comment: Your teacher may not want you to use things not covered in class but if you want more, have a look at conditionals (you can do a search on this very site about this topic).

Comment: @永劫回帰 très bien, je pensais qu'il y avait déjà une expression toute faite pour le dire. Ma prof n'a rien contre les initiatives si on en abuse pas et si on les utilise à bon escient. Dans ce cas je vais aller faire un petit tour du côté du conditionnel.

Comment: Even if I happen to understand French you should only use English or Japanese for the sake of other users. I don't know how far you went in your curriculum but conditionals might be considered a "big jump" (it is not covered (well there are some references to it but they are hidden) in Minna no nihongo I for example)

Comment: We both are French (at least native speaker) well. I have Minna no nihongo but this is hard for me to work on this kind of subject alone.

Comment: MNN (Minna no Nihongo) is just the worst book ever to learn on one's own. A great book on that respect is *a dictionary of basic Japanese grammar*. Maybe if you're ok with it, you could just drop the *If I have some* and make it implicit.

Comment: You can also have a look at this: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar or at http://imabi.net/ (and if you prefer French there is also ici-japon.com but I don't recommend it so much)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most naturally, one would say:

> 「それから、しゅくだいがあればしゅくだいをします。」 or
>
> 「それから、しゅくだいがあればそれをします。」 or
>
> 「それから、しゅくだいがあればします。」

You will hear all three from native speakers.  How it is taught outside of Japan or in Japanese-as-a-foreign-language in general, I have no idea.

The repeating of 「しゅくだい」 in the first sentence is ***not*** a typo.  In Japanese, it is completely fine to repeat words like that in informal speech.